# $\pi_{n}(X_{G})$ when $G$ is finite and acts freely on $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, equivariant-cohomology

When $X\in\mathbf{sSet}_{\ast}$ and $G$ a finite group (it may be considered a constant simplicial group) that acts freely on $X$. My question is

> Can I express $\pi_{n}(X_{G})$ in terms of $\pi_{n}(X)$ and $G$?
>
> If it does not happen, what if $X$ is $n$-connected?

Comment: If $G$ acts properly discontinuously on a nice enough topological space (the realization of a simplicial set should do), then $X$ is a cover of $X_G$ and by a standard argument from algebraic topology $\pi_n(X_G) \cong \pi_n (X)$ when $n \geq 2$ and for $n=1$, the map the projection map is an injection map on the level of fundamental groups. I'd guess things happen similarly here too.

Comment: Thanks PVAL. Any reference to find that conclussion?

Comment: All of the statements I said should be available in Hatcher or another standard algebraic topology text. I don't know the reference for a proof of these things in the simplicial set world, but I imagine they use similar ideas.

Comment: All of the things are rather direct consequences of the homotopy lifting property for covering spaces.

Comment: Do you mean the fixed point set $X^G$?

Comment: @Mike G was assumed to act freely.

Comment: My bad. Then as PVAL says higher homotopy groups are preserved under taking covers.